# Moving rows in R using the moveMe function

Tags: r

I am attempting to move the last row of a large data frame (331) to the top row using R. I am trying to use the moveme function to move rows instead of columns (as there are 149 columns). Any advise? My current code (which works for moving columns) is this:

```
moveMe <- function(data, tomove, where = "last", ba = NULL) {
  temp <- setdiff(names(data), tomove)
  x <- switch(
    where,
    first = data[c(tomove, temp)],
    last = data[c(temp, tomove)],
    before = {
      if (is.null(ba)) stop("must specify ba column")
      if (length(ba) > 1) stop("ba must be a single character string")
      data[append(temp, values = tomove, after = (match(ba, temp)-1))]
    },
    after = {
      if (is.null(ba)) stop("must specify ba column")
      if (length(ba) > 1) stop("ba must be a single character string")
      data[append(temp, values = tomove, after = (match(ba, temp)))]
    })
  x
}

dataframe<- moveMe(dataframe, r("Deidentified"), "first")
```

I want the output to move my row, but it currently is outputting this.

```
dataframe<- moveMe(dataframe, r("Deidentified"), "first")
```

> Error in r("Deidentified") : could not find function "r"

Comment: Additionally, I want to avoid writing out 149 column names to identify the row.

Comment: Are only looking for code review, or look for alternative solution? Because you could so stg like `dat[c(nrow(dat), seq(nrow(dat) - 1)), ]`

Comment: You're calling the function `r("Deidentified")` and R is telling you that it doesn't know what the function `r` is.

Comment: I am looking for an alternative solution! I will try the dat(c(now) solution. I was just wondering if the Moveme function also works for rows